# Laravel Eloquent Query Issue with Sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder, mysql-error-1055

I'm a newbie in Laravel and I tried to connect two tables with `SUM` of one column along with other columns, But it's returned an error and I don't know how to fix that.

```
$sinv =DB::table('salesinvoices')
           ->leftJoin('customers','customers.id','=','salesinvoices.customer')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum((salesinvoices.grand_total)-(salesinvoices.isslnrtn_amt)) as sumgrand'),'customers.short_name')
            ->where('salesinvoices.is_deleted','0')
            ->where('salesinvoices.is_returned','!=','1')
            ->where('salesinvoices.paidstatus','!=','1')
            ->groupBy('salesinvoices.customer_id')
            ->get();
```

If I remove the `customers.short_name` it will return the answer
And this is the error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'agrimerptow.customers.short_name' isn't in GROUP BY"

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel. Either add `customers.short_name` to your `groupBy()` or remove it from your `select()`. If you need it but don't want to include it in your `groupBy()` you'll have to query it separately

Comment: No problem... You're welcome.